# Why we are making index.android.bundle file while do changes in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, reactjs, android-monitor

Every time I will need to make **index.android.bundle** file in android studio.

**Command 1: react-native bundle --platform --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android /app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle/ --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res**

**Command 2 : react-native run-android.**

Please let me know is we need to hit every time to see the little changes on simulator or i 'm doing something wrong in that....

Also please tell me how to enable android monitor for debugging the change or check the log of react native files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got a solution of this problem, React-naive js is based on Instant refreshing with that user is able to see the result in simulator..

In this you need to follow these steps before starting Developing in react js

1. Open two command prompt window and run one window : react-native run-android and other on below command npm start.
2. react-native run-android
3. Now may be you will got an error : Unable to connect to development server
4. Now you need to run "npm start"
5. You simulator is running with the localhost:8081 server instantly

You can check in the browser as well : localhost:8081 that is showing react packager server is running.

After this by pressing Ctrl + D then Ctrl + M for debugging or Reloading your changes in the simulator .

You can check this above methods for get rid of issues .

Thanks!